# SwiftUI: Navigation link alignment with the newer navigation stack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using the new `NavigationStack` and I have a `VStack` with the code below:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    NavigationLink(post.phrase, value: post)
      .lineLimit(2)
      .font(.system(size: 20))
      .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
      .foregroundColor(.black)
    Text(post.Translation.chinese)
            .lineLimit(1)
}
```

The `NavigationLink` is always centrally aligned but the `Text` is ok which is left aligned. Is there a way to force the 2-line `NavigationLink` to align to the left?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will correctly align the navigation link:

```
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
              NavigationLink(value: post) {
                Text(post.phrase)
                  .lineLimit(2)
                  .font(.system(size: 20))
                  .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                  .foregroundColor(.black)
              }
              Text(post.Translation.chinese)
                .lineLimit(1)
            }
```